# How to apply a specific shape to a div?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I have this shape to do on a website: [image]

Unfortunately, I don't exactly know how to do it.

I thought about `clip-path`, here is some code I tried:

HTML (Vue):

```
...
<div class="col-md-7">
  <q-gallery-carousel class="gallery-cropper" infinite autoplay :src="gallery"></q-gallery-carousel>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery-cropper {

  clip-path: polygon(
    100% 0%,
    100% 100%,
    10% 100%,
    0% 0%
  );
}
```

Which gives me this (photos are not the same but you get the thing):

[image]

Right now, I need to do the top left rounded corner. Do I have to enter all thousands of coordinates manually... ?

Also I know that `clip-path` isn't compatible with IE. I heard about loading a manual SVG, but again will I have to enter all coordinates manually ? And does a SVG apply to a `<div>` ?

Comment: Is there a solid reason the image itself cannot contain the clipping?

Comment: border-top-left-radius doesn't do the job?

Comment: @hungerstar : Well, problem is that if we change photo we need to redo this in photoshop or something, so let's say no

Comment: @IgorRibeiro : No, doesn't work, seems like clip-path override everything as a shape

Comment: @PierreHofman you can overlay one image on top of another. If you're going to be changing out images regularly then it makes _some_ sense not to incorporate it into the image. If the image is going to be changed once a year, then Photoshop is a solid option. It takes about 30 seconds to add the shape to the image. Here's a [demo SVG overlay](https://jsfiddle.net/pga6Lmap/).

Comment: You should put that in an answer @hungerstar.

Comment: It worked for me @hungerstar, please post it as an answer :)
And thanks a lot !
Problem right now is the `position: relative` which breaks a bit my bootstrap, but well it's ok ;)

Comment: @PierreHofman how are you applying the solution? Are you applying it to a grid column? i.e. `col-**-**`. You should be able to apply this solution without affecting Bootstrap.

Comment: Yes I'm applying it to col-md-7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the image is not going to change too often, applying the shape to the image via Photoshop should be quick an painless. If the image is going to be swapped out somewhat regularly then it makes more sense to create an overlay for the image(s).

Here's an example using an SVG but could be done with PNG.

```css
.img-overlay {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px; /* prevents overlay from expanding beyond native width of image */
}
.img-overlay svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* Make image responsive. */
.img-overlay img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-overlay">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400?image=84">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 400"><path d="M27,71.5a71.43,71.43,0,0,0,2.48,18.73L105,399H-71V0H98.5A71.5,71.5,0,0,0,27,71.5Z" fill="#b3b3b3"/></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `border-top-left-radius`:

```
.gallery-cropper {
    clip-path: polygon(
    100% 0%,
    100% 100%,
    10% 100%,
    0% 0%
    );
    border-top-left-radius: 30px; /* change this value until reach the results */
}
```

Comment: clip-path overrides border-top-left-radius and other border-radius, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this with CSS3 `skew()` transformation.

- Wrap `img` element in a container `div` with some appropriate `border-top-left-radius` value.
- Apply some `skewX()` transformation to image container.
- Apply same degree of `skewX()` transformation to `img` element but in opposite direction.

**Required HTML:**

```
<div class="image-holder">
  <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="Image Description" />
</div>
```

**Necessary CSS:**

```
.image-holder {
  border-top-left-radius: 70px;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: skewX(12deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-holder img {
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: skewX(-12deg);
}
```

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(teal, skyblue);
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-holder {
  border-top-left-radius: 70px;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: skewX(12deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-holder img {
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: skewX(-12deg);
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/b807c2282ab0a491bd5c5c1051c6d312_rP0kQjJ.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is that it applies a distorsion on the image, see here: https://puu.sh/xzrRl/f88c46711a.png

Comment: @PierreHofman Once you will inversely `skew()` the image it will not distort anymore.

Comment: I'm using Quasar Framework with Vuejs, I don't really know how to do a fiddle of that. Your code works very well on a single image, but when applying on `q-gallery-carousel` it distorts the images inside ( http://quasar-framework.org/components/image-gallery.html#Image-Gallery-Carousel )