# I want to get this CSS shape and have a background puicture inside it

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How to create this shape using CSS and HTML only?

[image: Shape with rounded side]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: [A Similar Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200094/how-to-apply-a-specific-shape-to-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve similar shapes to this using the `border-radius` property. You can play around with the values until you get the perfect shape you want.

HTML:

```
<div class="shape">
  <img src="https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/2RTQTEA00I.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.shape{
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
  margin:50px auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:0 0 10% 50%;
}
.shape img{
  max-height:100%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p80b7fp6/